# Listing lines that start with a number and end in a sequence

Tags: bash, grep

So basically, I need to list lines with their line numbers that contain one or more words that start with 42 and end in a sequence of any number (but not zero) of character X.

so far what I got is:

```
ls | grep -En "^42" filename
```

It just the *end in a sequence of any number* part that I don't understand.

This is for bash by the way.

Comment: What does `but not zero of character X` mean?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, hopefully it make sense now

Comment: Please post a sample of your corpus and your desired output.

Comment: In addition to providing a corpus sample, please take care to include examples covering the corner cases (Do the *words* or the *lines* end with X? What do you consider a "word"? Are the start and the end substrings immediately adjacent?).

Comment: ... and do you mean to ask the question in the title, or the one in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(some sequence of commands) | grep -E '^42.*X+$'
```

Will search the output of the sequence of commands for lines matching the following criteria:

- `^` - The beginning of the line
- `42` - The numeral four followed by the numeral two
- `.*` - Any sequence of zero or more characters
- `X+` - Any sequence of one or more of the character `X`
- `$` - The end of the line

The following examples will match:

```
42freebleXXXX
42X
42 partriges in 42 pear trees X
```

The following will not:

```
42Xy
42x
52freebleX
```

Comment: You also want to set `LC_ALL=C`, otherwise `.*` fail to match invalid unicode character.